# Javascript window.onLoad element content not changing

Tags: javascript, html

Im having a problem with changing an elements content

HTML Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Javascript
function promptLogin()
{
    var person=prompt("Please enter your name","User");

    if (person!=null)
    {
        x="Hello " + person + ", welcome to JBA Limited";
        document.getElementById("topBar_message").innerHTML=x;
    }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<script>window.onLoad = promptLogin()</script>
<header>
    <div class="bul_header_topBar">
        <p id="topBar_message">Welcome to JBA Limited</p>
    </div>
```

I am unsure of the problem but I fear the problem is with the function being called before the webpage is loaded and therefore no id is present. Either that or have spelt/defined something wrong.

Bull

Answer (score 1):

You need to strip the `()` from `promptLogin`

edit: oh yeah, and it's `onload`, not `onLoad`

bigger edit:

`window.onload` waits until your DOM is loaded, so there's no way it's not there. This is just a case where you are trying to pass a method that has already been run. The `()` at the end of `promptLogin` means "`window.onLoad` is equal to the return value of this function", not what you are looking for ("`window.onLoad` equals this function").

Also, once upon a time browsers were less case-sensitive when it came to these callbacks, but now they are. it's `window.onload`.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your dom is not loaded yet, so when you try to "get" your element its not loaded/there yet.

You can either add what I suggest below, or leave everything as it is, except remove the onload etc.. and put that call (with the script tag) at the very bottom of your page.

```
 //at the bottom of your page within script tags
 <script>promptLogin()</script>
```

Put this code at the bottom (under) your dom.

1. add the code below to your page, at bottom within script tags.
2. remove this window.onLoad = promptLogin()

   (function()
       {
          var person=prompt("Please enter your name","User");

   ```
      if (person!=null)
         {
             x="Hello " + person + ", welcome to JBA Limited";
             document.getElementById("topBar_message").innerHTML=x;
         }
   ```

   })()

Comment: Thanks James, I just started to learn js so this is really helpful to me.

Comment: any function called by window.onload is executed after the DOM is completely loaded https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onload "The load event fires at the end of the document loading process. At this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all the images and sub-frames have finished loading."

Answer (score 0):

What el_bob says is correct, however rather than just stripping `()` I would use the anonymous function syntax because it is more common thus more readable:

```
window.onload = function(){
    promptLogin();
}
```

The main advantage of this syntax is that you can make multiple calls:

```
window.onload = function(){
    promptLogin();
    anotherFunction();
    thirdFunction();
}
```